# Buildroot and framebuffer

Tags: linux, qemu, display, buildroot, framebuffer

I am very new to embedded programming so please have some understanding if i sound dumb.
Recently i have built a linux kernel using buildroot tool.
These are the commands i used:

```
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
make
```

When building is done i run the image using qemu with the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -M pc -kernel ./output/images/bzImage -drive \ file=./output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw -append "root=/dev/vda console=ttyS0" -net nic,model=virtio -net user
```

The problem i have is that i cant find /dev/fb0, and i dont know how can this be configured. My goal is to be able to draw on qemu display.

Answer (score 0):

Enable it on make linux-menuconfig

Framebuffer devices